# Jquery - get total Length - Before / After specific class name element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code, I can get total items length as 5.

But, not sure how to get total items length after class name "selected". It have to be 3. But, i am not sure what code to use. Also, before class name "selected" how many items. it have to be 1.

It may be silly question. Hope it will useful for my learning.

```js
var totalItems = $('.wrapper .item').length;
var SelectedItemLen = $('.wrapper .item.selected').length;
console.log(totalItems);
console.log(SelectedItemLen);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item selected"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) of the selected element within it's siblings and calculate before and after based on it

```js
var totalItems = $('.wrapper .item').length;
var selectedPosition = $('.wrapper .item.selected').index() + 1;

console.log('Before =', selectedPosition - 1)
console.log('After =', totalItems - selectedPosition)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item  selected"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nextAll` & `prevAll` as explained in other answer. But if you have multiple `.item.select` elements & you want elements until next/prev `.item.select` then you can use [`nextUntil` & `prevUntil`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing_siblings.asp) like below.

```js
var totalItems = $('.wrapper .item').length;
var SelectedItemLen = $('.wrapper .item.selected').length;

console.log(totalItems);
console.log(SelectedItemLen);

$('.wrapper .item.selected').each((index, item) => {
  let nextItems = $(item).nextUntil('.item.selected').length;
  var prevItems = $(item).prevUntil('.item.selected').length;
  console.log('selected item ' + (index + 1) + ' - next items = ' + nextItems);
  console.log('selected item ' + (index + 1) + ' - prev items = ' + prevItems);
});
```

```css
div.item {
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

div.item.selected {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item selected"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item selected"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```